# Python Programe that Jumbles Words Puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.2

I'm new to python and I was just working on this application

```
import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("hello","goodbye","smile","evening","daytime")

#

# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)

# create a variable to see if the guess is correct
correct = word

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble =""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]

# start the game
print( \
"""
        Welcome to the anagram quiz!

   Unscramble the letters to make a word.
(Press the enter key at the prompt to quit.)
""")
print ("The jumble is:", jumble)

guess = input("\nYour guess: ")
guess = guess.lower()

while (guess != correct) and (guess != ""):
    print ("Sorry, that's not it.")
    guess = input("Your guess: ")
    guess = guess.lower()

if guess == correct:
    print ("That's it!  You guessed it!\n")

print ("Thank you for playing.")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Which as you can see jumbles up a word for the user to guess what the word is, I need to be able to to improve this so the user gets a hint if they are stuck and add a scoring system that rewards those who solve a jumble without asking for a hint.

I've tried for hours and got no where, can you please help me add that functionality in.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your specific issue?

Comment: What does your hint and scoring system code look like?  Scoring could be based on time to solve plus set bonus for not needing hint...

Answer (score 2):

For the hint part:  if the player guesses wrong a specified number of times, he gets the option to ask for a hint. The hint will be something you generate along with the sequence of words to choose from, in pair form. So you'll have a word and a hint to give out for it when the player gets stuck.

```
WORDS=[['hello','greeting'],['evening','sunset'],etc.]
```

As for the score part:  you can do time based scoring, where they lose points every second until they guess correctly, or guess based scoring, where they lose points for every incorrect guess.

Comment: Will you be able to write that code for me? As every attempt i've tried to do point scoring along with the hint it just does not work, literally spent all day trying to do this. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: This is not a "please send me the codes" service. If the code you've shown is actually your own, then writing the code that was described to you should be easy for you. Seriously, give it a shot, and if you get stuck then ask a new (detailed) question.